# Linux: even with route, packets not going over the interface

Tags: linux, routing, iproute

I apologize but this is a question I jotted down when debugging another problem, so I can't provide any additional information.

Anyway: suppose we have no firewall rules, and the following route appears if we invoke `ip route show`:

```
192.168.8.0/24 dev wlp3s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.8.3
```

Question: How is it possible that packets destined for an address in 192.168.8.0/24 would not appear on the interface wlp3s0, according to tcpdump? Assuming that 192.168.8.0/24 is the most specific route for the address. I have/had no reason to believe that there were any policy routes in place, or any routing tables in operation besides the default.

(No, this isn't a homework problem, I just didn't have the patience to make an SE question about this because I was too frustrated with the original problem I was debugging)

Thank you

Comment: Run `ip rule ls` to make sure you have no policy routing rules. Also run `ip route get 192.168.8.something` to check routing result for your address that is not routed properly

Comment: Unfortunately it's a totally theoretical question since it's something I came across a few months ago. However, I'm pretty sure there weren't any more specific routes or policy routes. (Could be wrong, but I'm also curious about other possibilities). Thanks